# How to resolve ambiguous overload for 'operator=' in string

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading

I am trying to create a class that can be implicity cast to a variety of different types, both primitives and custom defined classes.  One of the types that I want to be able to cast to is an std::string.  Below is an example class that can cast to various different types.  It throws the error "error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’".  This is because std::string has an assignment operator from a CharT which the compiler can create from an int. My question is, is it possible to have a class that can both implicity convert to an integer or a string type?

```
class Test {
public:
    operator double() const {
        return 3.141592;
    }
    operator std::int64_t() const {
        return -999;
    }
    operator std::uint64_t() const {
        return 999;
    }
    operator bool() const {
        return true;
    }
    operator std::string() const {
        return "abcd";
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::string test_str = Test();
    test_str = Test();
    std::cout << test_str;
}
```

Interestingly, when I assign to test_str on the same line that I define it, the compiler throws no errors because it's using the simple constructor rather than an assignment operator, but it errors on the following line.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that `std::string test_str = Test();` is **not** an assignment. It creates an object using the constructor that takes an object of type `Test`. The `=` sign is part of the constructor syntax, not an assignment operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::string` has several overloaded `operator=`s with following parameters: `std::string`, `const char *`, `char`, `std::initializer_list`.

For your code to work, the compiler needs to choose one, but at least two are potentially suitable: the `std::string` one; and the `char` one, using an implicit conversion from one of your scalar `operator`s. Even though the latter would cause an ambiguity later on, the compiler doesn't seem to reach that point.

The solution is to make a single templated conversion `operator`, and to restrict it to specific types with SFINAE:

Then following works:

```
template <auto V, typename, typename...>
inline constexpr auto value = V;

template <typename T, typename ...P>
concept one_of = (std::same_as<T, P> || ...);

class Test
{
  public:
    template <one_of<int, float, std::string> T>
    operator T() const
    {
        if constexpr (std::same_as<T, int>)
            return 42;
        else if constexpr (std::same_as<T, float>)
            return 42;
        else if constexpr (std::same_as<T, std::string>)
            return "foo";
        else
            static_assert(value<false, T>, "This shouldn't happen.");
    }
};
```

The `static_assert` isn't really necessary, since we already have `requires`. It merely provides a nicer error if you add more types to the `requires` and forget a branch.

Note `value<false, T>` instead of `false`. Trying to put `false` there directly would cause some compilers to emit an error unconditionally, even if the branch is not taken ([this is allowed, but not required](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.1)). Using an expression dependendent on `T` convinces the compiler to delay the test until an actual instantiation (because for all it knows, `value` could be specialized to become `true` for some `T`).

---

> when I assign to test_str on the same line that I define it

This is an initialization, not assignment. It calls a constructor, not `operator=`.

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm further revealing my ignorance here, but I'm fairly confused by how you're defining `value` there.  What are the typenames supposed to be (they can't be float or string or whatnot), why are there two autos and what is V?

Also, I think that the whole purpose of that static_assert is just to provide feedback when this cast operator fails, so it should work even without that else statement.  I added another `else if` for the std::string type but the compiler is still complaining about an ambiguous overload to operator=  Remember, I'm trying to do this completely implicity.

Comment: @kevin63857 My bad, fixed. `value` is a variable template, I've added a short explanation.

Comment: Wow, that it some proper compiler black magic.  Thank you so much.  I would certainly up vote if I had enough reputation.